# Set up several VPN connections through Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, vpn

Is it possible to set up several VPN connections through Windows Vista? if so, how?

Comment: comment by Sjuul Janssen: Open VPN connections or host a VPN server?

Comment: comment by [Mohammad](http://superuser.com/users/17178/mohammad): I don't know what you mean actually? I'm a beginner. I mean creating VPN connection that I showed in following image: http://www.picfront.org/d/5f06cRjYL/Untitled.jpg

Answer (score 0):

See this article : [Configure VPN Connection Introduction on Windows Vista](http://vpngates.com/config_vista.htm).

This article shows in great detail and with screenshots, how to set up a VPN towards a server named ‘vpngates.com’ (replace this server and its IP address by these of the VPN servers that you're trying to connect to).

You may create several VPN connections with various servers. But you should connect to one at a time, or you'll need to solve some more advanced technicalities.

Comment: comment by [Mohammad](http://superuser.com/users/17178/mohammad): Thanks harrymc. Actually, I knew how I can create a VPN connection, But I'm gonna set up several VPN connections via one OS(like Vista). Well, What do you mean by advanced technicalities? Can we create several VPN connections with the same servers?

Comment: @Mohammad: I never tried, but in theory you can have as many concurrent VPN connections as you like, each configured with its own IP segment. Depending on what you're trying to achieve (such as Internet connection), some acrobatics may be required for the routes involved. It's important that none of the VPN servers locks you in tunnel mode. You may also need to study split-tunneling. And the VPN servers involved had better be fully RFC-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad, I think your problem lies with one checkbox.

You can actually use several VPN connections from your PC simultaniously if:

1. Create those VPN connections
2. Right-click on any of those VPN connections in Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network connections
3. In the VPN's Properties select tab "Networking"
4. Select Properties of TCP/IPv4
5. Click on the button "Advanced"
6. Uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network"

Do this for every VPN connection and then you can use them all at once.

Comment: comment by [Mohammad](http://superuser.com/users/17178/mohammad): Hi Andrei Drynov. I've done what you said literally but there is a problem. I've created two VPN connection as you said (for testing) , The first one connected successfully but whenever I double click on the second one , the first one disconnected and the second one don't connect anymore !!! BTW : Both of my VPN connection have the same GateWay. What's wrong with it?

Comment: To use two or more VPN connections to the same server you must configure VPN services to different ports using Windows's Routing and Remote Access.